# Как вставить функцию возвращающую строку в строку?

Tags: php

```
function foo() {return 'bar';}
echo "{foo()}"; // Ошибка! {foo()}
```

Comment: Только если `"". foo() . ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько путей:

1. Через переменную.

   ```
   $foo = foo();
   echo "foo={$foo}\n";
   ```
2. Через конкатенацию.

   ```
   echo "foo=" . foo() . "\n";
   ```
3. Через метод класса.

   ```
   class Bar
   {
       function foo()
       {
           return 'bar';
       }
   }
   $bar = new Bar();
   echo "foo={$bar->foo()}\n";
   ```

Фигурные скобки везде нужны для однообразия и исключения опечаток в случаях вида `"{$foo}bar"` - лучше сразу писать со скобками, чем потом, после рефакторинга с заменой строк, мучительно искать где же что-то не выводится или выводится не то.

Comment: 1. Фигурные скобки не нужны.

Comment: @Khipster напишите свой ответ

Comment: Я просто немного поправил. Знал бы ответ - не задавал бы вопрос.